# For $f \in \mathbb{F}[x], a \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]/\langle f \rangle, b \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ what would $ab$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It seems intuitive that $ab = \texttt{lift}(a, \mathbb{F}_q[x]) b  \ (\mbox{mod }f)$ with the result being in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]/\langle f \rangle$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you mean by lift, but yes the result is in the quotient ring. Just take some $a'$ in the class $a$ and compute a'b. This is a representaive  of the class you seek as result.

Comment: Maybe I should have stated my question as does $ab = ac \in \mathbb{F}[x]/\langle f \rangle$ where $c \equiv b\ (\mbox{mod }f) \in \mathbb{F}[x]/\langle f \rangle$.  Sorry for the confusion.  You answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

The result definitely has to be an element of the quotient ring.

There are several ways to make sense of the product in a formal way, 
but all of them are equivalent.

- One can say  $ab$ is the equivalence class of $a'b$ where $a'$ is some element of the class $a$. This is considering $F[x]/(f)$ as an $F[x]$-module.
- One can consider the image of $b$ in $F[x]/(f)$ and then form the product in the ring  $F[x]/(f)$.

Both give the same. I think the former is somewhat closer in spirit to what is specifically written.